# Identify Orthogonal Proj. and Reflection within given choice of Matrices.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

The problem states that out of five given matrices, one represents an Orthogonal Projection onto a line and another a Reflection about a line; I'm supposed to identify them.

Rather than list the matrices here, I'd like to understand how one would go about identifying these two transformations. I should probably state that the matrices are all 3x3, and all have a coefficient of 1/3 (one of them -1/3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An orthogonal projection matrix is a matrix $P$ which satisfies $P^T = P$ and $P^2 = P$. You can check these conditions easily. And a reflection is an orthogonal matrix (i.e. if you take the dot product of two different columns, you get $0$) whose determinant is $-1$ (the eigenvalues should be all 1's, except for one eigenvalue of $-1$) [ I'd be surprised if you hadn't seen determinants -- they're at the beginning of almost all intro linear algebra books these days, with inane ways of calculating them by hand. ]

If you're [reflecting a vector $v$ across the plane determined by vector $a$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_%28mathematics%29), the resultant vector is $v - 2 \frac{v \cdot a}{a \cdot a} a = (I - 2 \frac{1}{||a||^2} a a^T) {v}$. without loss of generality, you can assume $||a|| = 1$, so see if you can write the reflection matrix in the form of $I - 2 a a^T$ for a unit vector $a$. But the determinant check is easier.

Answer (score 1):

An orthogonal projection has $A^2 = A^* = A$, where $A^*$ denotes the adjoint, that is $A^* = A^t$ for real matrices. Any such matrix is an orthogonal projection. A projection onto a line moreover has ${\rm rank}\, A = 1$.

A reflection around a line is characterised by $A^tA = {\rm Id}$, $A^2 = {\rm Id}$, $\det A = 1$ and $A \ne {\rm Id}$.

Comment: thank you but we haven't yet learned about the adjoint or the determinant for that matter. We've mostly gone over Matrix Algebra, Linear transformations and Gauss Jordan reduction; are there other ways to identify those matrices?

Comment: A reflection has determinant 1?

Comment: @PeterFranek A reflection *about a line* in space ... yes. A refelction about a plane, the reflection one usually has in mind when thinking of a reflection in 3d, no.

Comment: Ok; maybe I had a termonilogy problem. But still, even if you suppose that $n$ is odd, the condition in your second paragraph describe all of $\mathrm{SO}(n)\setminus \{Id\}$ which is more.

Comment: @PeterFranek Yes, you are right. The reflections around a line are the rotations with rotation angle $\pi$, which I wanted to describe. With an added $A^2 = {\rm Id}$, it should work.

Comment: Ok, now with the $A^2=\mathrm{Id}$ it probably holds in $\mathbb{R}^3$; I believe that this is where the question aims.

Comment: @PeterFranek  Yes, as $\pm \frac 13 \in \mathbb R$ and the OP talks about $3\times 3$ matrices.

Comment: Martini, I will delete this remark, just.. what is "OP"? I see it often here.

Comment: @PeterFranek I always understood it as "opening/original post"